# Measuring CPU usage on an pSOS operating system

Tags: intel

I have a piece of computer hardware in my lab that is running an Intel Celeron CPU with 300 MHz and 128k bytes of secondary cache. The hardware documentation says it's running an real time operating system (**RTOS**) called **pSOS** (Portable Software On Silicon). I wanted to measure what is the load on the CPU to know if I can load more stuff into it.

Because this is legacy hardware, I am having a hard time trying to find any information or guide on how to measure CPU usage for this chip.

My best guess is that I can do that using **TELNET** and the correct command to read CPU usage and memory allocation. I can already **TELNET** to the CPU and by using the `help` command I get a list of commands. The problem is, I have no idea what is the exact command I have to type in order to read that kind of info. And I am afraid to mess up the CPU.

---Updates

This OS don't support `uname` nor `top` commands.

But  it does support `arp`, `netstat`, `ifconfig`.

Comment: Do you know what OS it's running? Or could you post a transcript of your Telnet session? (Make sure IP addresses, usernames and passwords are redacted.) Alternatively, your DHCP server might give you a clue what it's running, or run `nmap -O -sV 10.0.0.1` from a Linux machine to tell you what OS is running on 10.0.0.1.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. We almost don't have access to the inner part of the hardware. The only way we interface with it is through an ethernet port. When I come back from the lab tomorrow I will update this post with some more info about the TELNET session. And I will also try the linux command as well. Thanks @traal!

Comment: Measuring CPU usage is an aspect of the operating system. In a general sense, unless the CPU is actually "asleep" (which is a hardware state), the "CPU usage" is always "100%". What the operating system measures is how of the CPU is doing something BESIDES spinning idle waiting for an interrupt by an external device or timer. But "spinning idle" is, well "CPU usage". So, short story, it's up to your operating system, to answer this. This is not (typically) a hardware problem.

Comment: @WillHartung, is there a way to discover what OS is running on this hardware? Remember, as I said, we are limited here to only interact with this hardware using an ethernet port and TELNET sessions. Unless there is something else we missed (and that's possible, as we are not computer engineers, but automation engineers).

Comment: TELNET usually gives you some shell, try to execute `uname -a` there to gather information about the system

Comment: @Tommylee2k, I have tried that and `uname` nor `top` are recognizable commands in this OS.

Comment: "I can already TELNET to the CPU" - no, you cannot. Intel started to include MINIX in their CPU's much later :-) (and even that likely does not include a telnet daemon)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, maybe I should have said "TELNET to the OS"? :)

Comment: Hey everyone, OS type identified. It is caled [pSOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSOS_(real-time_operating_system)).

Comment: I was about to challenge that this question fits here - But, as psos+ has been discontinued 19 years ago, we probably need to accept this question. I wasn't even aware psos would run on Intel. Only knew it to be supporting 68000

Comment: does "help" show anything like "task list"?

Comment: It doesn't @IgorSkochinsky

Comment: can you post the output of “help”?

Comment: If you have access to an SDK for the system then writing a simple busy loop program (either a fixed number of iterations or an infinite loop with output every *n* iterations) could provide insight.  Run it as a non-realtime (or lowest priority) task and again as a high-priority realtime task.  The difference in runtimes should give you an idea of how much headroom (idle time) there is on the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you're ending up in *psh*, the pSos+ shell.

Note what you have is an embedded system that is completely customized - So what you can and cannot do is entirely depending on what the system builder wanted you to be able to do.

psh+ manual (for PowerPCS, but I'd assume Intel is similar) can be found here:

http://bagfed.free.fr/pSOS/PSOS_Programmers_reference.pdf

(starting from pg. 1-114) Just browsed this shortly to find some sort of system load indicators, but a quick glance did not reveal anything.

System load information can only be retrieved if the realtime kernel actually collects it - And in the case of PSos, I'm afraid it doesn't. So, no luck.

Comment: Hello @tofro, I also found this manual a few minutes ago. And I am also getting to the same conclusion, that it will probably not be possible to retrieve that info...

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, knowing what OS is running is really the key. `help` as a valid command could be any variant of *nix, but also many other operating systems and even an application that is processing the telnet command instead of an OS shell process. But assuming it is some variant of Linux or a similar OS, try the `top` command. The options vary, but typically it starts off running showing the "biggest" programs at the top sorted either by memory usage or CPU usage. It also lists some overall system information, such as total memory available and total memory used. The specifics vary a bit by OS version.

One other item that would be helpful to figure out system capacity is the memory. You mentioned 300 Mhz. (speed) and 128k secondary cache, but not the amount of total system RAM. A quick search shows system of that vintage with 32 - 64 Meg., but I wouldn't be surprised to see quite a range from "single task" systems with less to top-of-the-line servers with much more, though Celeron has always been on the budget side so this was probably never a top-of-the-line server.

Comment: The scarce and really bad quality documentation we have about this hardware says it has "32 to 256 Mbytes Synchronous DRAM with parity /
ECC". So, I see that my first task is to discover which OS is running in this hardware. How could I do that?

Comment: @FTM - Lots of unknowns. But basically you start with whatever works. For example, if the top command works that my give you some clues. What does the help command tell you? What is the initial prompt when you log in via telnet?

Comment: unfortunately lots of them. I just tried it out using TELNET and it says that both `top` and `uname` are unknown commands. When I log in using TELNET, the only message I get back is "Welcome to Telnet Shell session".

Comment: @FTM what about any other common *nix command? I'd try `echo`, `set`, `cd`, `pwd`, `ls` and, just in case it runs any MSDOS derivative, `dir`.

Comment: both uname and top are external commands. just because the shell doesn't find them doesn't mean it's not a unix/linux/minix machine, perhaps they've been removed from /bin (or /usr/bin), or you don't have a $PATH set to there. what does `ls -lR /` show ?

Comment: You could use `man ls` or something, and see if the man pages give any clue about what software distribution it's running

Comment: @Wilson, I tried it out but the `man` command was not found. @Tommylee2k, I tried that command out but that seems to have overloaded the system. But I did got some interesting info about the folder structure. I will have to wait for my coleaguee in a different time zone to wake up and reset the hardware because I can't communicate with it now. :)

Comment: @FTM if `ls` works, then that is more likely *nix and you can try to see if there is a `/proc` directory. If there is a `cat` command as well, then everything becomes much easier (`cat /proc/loadavg` if it's actually Linux).

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, `ls` words, `cat` as well. But I don't have such a `/proc` directory.

Comment: @FTM then look at the filesystem - start with `ls /`, maybe even `ls -l /` (if it works), then `ls -l /*`, then look into the directories...  Lack of `/proc` says it's probably not Linux nor *BSD, or a very pruned one. Is there a `mount` command?

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, `ls -l /` works, but `ls -l /*` gives a "/*: illegal filename syntax" output. But "ls -lR /" works! Finally, the `mount` command works!

Comment: @FTM, yeah, you can look what directories `ls -lR /` shows and it will become more clear...

Comment: Hey everyone, OS type identified. It is caled [pSOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSOS_(real-time_operating_system)).

Comment: @FTM wikipedia claims pSOS is Motorola 68000 only. Are you sure it's not pSOS+? Anyway, since it's proprietary and not Linux and dead and there is no `/proc`, your best chance is finding someone who worked with pSOS[+].

Comment: The documentation says it is pSOS. But it is so badly written that I don't doubt it might be pSOS+. Anyhow, as measuring these stuff would be desirable but not a requirement, I think I am about to just give it up. :/

Comment: @ftm pSos+ was available for m68k, PPC and x86. You're right, originally (without the plus - and quite some time with the plus) it was m68k only.